# Open a child process to tail each file in config file?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am using config parser to parse a config file I need to tail each file in the files section in a separate terminal I am using python on mac

the code I wrote gets me all the things in the files section I need only the paths and need to tail each one of them in a separate child process

```
import ConfigParser

    import os

def ConfigSectionMap(section):
    dict1 = {}
    options = Config.options(section)
    for option in options:
        try:
            dict1[option] = Config.get(section, option)
            if dict1[option] == -1:
                DebugPrint("skip: %s" % option)
        except:
            print("exception on %s!" % option)
            dict1[option] = None
    return dict1

Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.read("/etc/harvest.conf")
print Config.sections()
print ConfigSectionMap("files")
```

sample config file is

> [section1]  host_prefix = true
>
> timestamp_prefix = true
>
> [section2]  host = localhost
>
> port = 1463
>
> pids = /var/run/harvester
>
> [files]  apache.access =  /var/log/apache2/access.log
>
> apache.errors = /var/log/apache2/errors.log
>
> mail =  /var/log/mail.log
>
> mysql.log =  /var/log/mysql.log
>
> mysql.err = /var/log/mysql.err
>
> syslog.err = /var/log/syslog.err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tail` is accepting multiple files, you can rely on it:

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
from subprocess import Popen

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/harvest.conf')
filenames = [value for name, value in config.items('files')]

process = Popen(['tail', '-f'] + filenames)
process.communicate()
```

Comment: will each file have its own process?

Comment: no, but tail can "tail" all the file in the same time. If you want to do it for each filenames, adapt and loop over it.

Comment: i don't know what you want and why. a simple for loop is ok, but then what ? their is no gain to do that until you want to do something specific. And this goal is important for knowing how to make that loop. You are not sharing lot of informations, so the rest is up to you :)